# Should check the method return value

Tags: java

Why in this case I get a message "Should check the method return value"?

```
if(!qty.contains("@"))
      mgm.addOrder(date, Integer.parseInt(qty));
else
{
      qty.replace("@", "");
      mgm.addOrder(date, Integer.parseInt(qty));
      mgm.startNew();
}
```

I get this message at: qty.replace("@", "");

The if statement has checked if @ is there, what else do I need to make it perfect?

Comment: `qty.replace("@", "")` doesn't actually change `qty`. It's a no-op if you do nothing with the result, rather than e.g. `qty = qty.replace("@", "");`.

Comment: @AndyTurner post an answer with that explanation and how the code should look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String#replace` returns a new `String` representing the results the `replace` operation.  You should assigning the results back to a `String`, otherwise they are lost

```
qty = qty.replace("@", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

`qty.replace("@", "")` doesn't actually change `qty`. It's a no-op if you do nothing with the result.

You should do something like:

```
qty = qty.replace("@", "");
```

If you don't, the following expression will throw a `NumberFormatException`, because `qty` still has an `@` sign in it:

```
Integer.parseInt(qty)
```